# Как передать svg в компонент?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, svg

Как передать svg в компонент? Нужно создать компонент в который я буду импортировать разные svg иконки. В компонент будет передаваться иконка и название.

Пример:

```
const ContextButton = ({icon, name}) => {
return (
    <div className="context-button">

    </div>
);
```

};

Пример использования:

```
<ContextButton icon="some-icon1" name="settings"/>
<ContextButton icon="some-icon2" name="turn off notifications"/>
```

Comment: Через background можно. Тот который в css. В css создаёте класс, и там задаёте поведение елементов которые будут использовать класс. Читайте справку css background

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для передачи svg в компонент можно использовать специальный компонент ReactSVG из библиотеки react-svg.
Пример:

```
import ReactSVG from 'react-svg';

const ContextButton = ({icon, name}) => {
    return (
        <div className="context-button">
            <ReactSVG src={require(`../icons/${icon}.svg`)} />
            <span>{name}</span>
        </div>
    );
};
```

В данном примере передается путь к svg файлу через require и отображается  с помощью компонента ReactSVG. Также в компоненте выводим название иконки.
При использовании компонента необходимо установить библиотеку react-svg:

```
npm install --save react-svg
```